# Home Page showing as a category page

Tags: magento2, cms, frontend

Our home page started showing up as a category page, rather than our normal home page (not a category page).

When I go to /cms I do see our normal home page.

I've checked the configuration and everything seems ok.  The layout files and template files haven't changed.

Can someone point me in a direction for this?  I can provide more info as needed.

Comment: I am still looking for feedback on this.  I haven't figured it out yet.  Any help would be appreciated.  Anything to look for on theme files, advice on database fix.  Anything.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this setting for that home category:

[image]

Comment: I don't think I explained this well.  Our home page is not a category listings page.  What I'm seeing a category listings page instead of it.  I am going to edit the question is its clearer.

Comment: can you please share website URL?

Comment: Than check for URL key for that CMS page: http://prntscr.com/c4u7ya

Comment: Also for layout: http://prntscr.com/c4u8bu

Comment: I have the cms page setup with that: http://prnt.sc/c4u9xw layout looks fine too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43870/discussion-between-sarfaraz-bheda-and-dan-joseph).

Comment: We talked things through in chat, but the problem still persists.  The basic setup is correct, rewrites are ok, etc.  I'm continuing to dig.